# How create select from object in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

How easy to create select list from object JS?

**Object:**

```
0: {UsersWork: "600", Name: "Salaria"},
1: {UsersWork: "700", Name: "Bavaria"}
```

I need create:

```
<select>
   <option value="600">Salaria</option>
   <option value="700">Bavaria</option>
</select>
```

I tried using `ng-option`:

```
<option ng-show="specializationSelect == {{value.UsersSpecializationIdSpecialization}}" value="{{value.UsersWorkSpaceIdUser}}" ng-repeat="(key, value) in options">{{value.DetailToUsersName}}</option>
```

Comment: Guys, please add some point to zero, because will banned here (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ng-options`

```
<select ng-options="person.UsersWork as person.Name for (objId, person) in persons"></select>
```

Assuming your data <strike>array</strike> object is in `$scope.persons` (sub this out for whatever)

Comment: But if `$scope.persons` is not array? I have object

Comment: So, `0` is a property in your object, such as `{ 0 : { prop1: "name" } }`?

Comment: Yes, my object is:  `0: {UsersWork: "600", Name: "Doma"}`

Comment: Thanks it works, but is created first option how as: `<option value="?"></option>` and after option from object

Comment: I it possible to do same as like: `<option ng-repeat="person.UsersWork as person.Name for (objId, person) in persons"`>?

Answer (score 1):

```js
$scope.options = {
  "Blue": "color_1",
  "Red": "color_2",
  "Green": "color_3"
}

<select ng-model="selected"
        ng-options="name for (name, value) in options">
```